# Can I use my extech pH 60 meter to measure soil pH if so how?

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, ph

Can I use my extech pH60 meter to measure soil pH if so how?
I included a link to the meter.

[Extech pH 60](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012W4HW2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a soil sample and mix it with distilled water. The most common ratio used for soil-water pH is 1:1 soil:water.
Stir the soil and solution and wait 15 minutes to 1 hour to set the slurry.
Measure the pH (check the temperature first).

Comment: In the video below it says to do 1:2 (1 part soil 2 parts distilled water) which is correct? https://youtu.be/int0FevLw8I

Comment: There is more sampling method. Ratio 1:2 is often used for soils containg high amount of organic material. Also electrolyte solutions (instead of DI water) are used. For detailed info please see https://www.academia.edu/3326561/Models_relating_soil_pH_measurements_in_water_and_calcium_chloride_that_incorporate_electrolyte_concentration

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great video showing how to do this
In the video below it says to do 1:2 (1 part soil 2 parts distilled water)  https://youtu.be/int0FevLw8I